# Listview doesn't appear in fragment

Tags: listview, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I'm trying to show a listview in a table. I had a lot of different problems but now, there is no error message anymore, so I don't know what do do.

The ListView is not shown. 
Could you please help me, I'm a beginner and this is my first ListView. Maybe I do it completely wrong. Watched a tutorial how to add static things to a fragment and I,m trying to adapt it for a listview.

Thank you very much.

Here is my code for the listview fragment:

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class Fragment3 extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ListView LView;
View v;
String[] values = {"test","test2","test3"};
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragement3_layout, null);
    return v;
}
public void onActivityCreated(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ListAdapter adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

}
}
```

And here is the code for the Fragmentpageradapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter1 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

String[] tabtitlearray = {"One","Two","List"};
public ViewPagerAdapter1 (FragmentManager manager){
   super(manager);
```

}

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position) {
        case 0: return new Fragment1();
        case 1: return new Fragment2();
        case 2: return new Fragment3();
    }

    return null;
}//festlegen was in welchem Fragment was angezeigt wird

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 3;//Anzahl der Tabs
}
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    return tabtitlearray[position];
}
}
```

And this is the Activity

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager viewpager;
TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    ViewPagerAdapter1 viewPagerAdapter1 = new ViewPagerAdapter1(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter1);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL); //Fuer das drehen damit TabLayout richtig ausgefuellt ist
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Last but not least the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry if this way is totally wrong. I'm just trying to understand how the different basics work.

Would be so glad if somebody helps me.

Thanks!

Comment: Listview should not have a height or width set To wrap_content

Comment: Thanks, but that seems not to be the problem. It doesn´t work with "match_parent" either.
Is the ArrayAdapter right? I think the information is not added to the listview, but there is no error, it´s just empty. I guess there is anything wrong with my logic in the code.

Comment: The static ones show only a textfield, which works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The onActivityCreated(...) was wrong.

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ListAdapter adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Thank you anyway.
Works!